# Loading partial view on button click only fires on the first click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, partial-views

I have the following code:

```
@model pedidosOnlineMVC.Models.SuperUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MySystem";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Administration</h2>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@using(var p = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Panel()))
{   
    using (p.BeginBody())
    {
        @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Register new  administrator").Id("btnReg")
        @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("List administrators").Id("btnList")
        @Html.Bootstrap().Button().Text("Search administrator").Id("btnSeek")   
        using (var ip = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Panel()))
        {
            using (ip.BeginBody())
            {
                <div id="partials">
                </div>
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

And the proper JQuery coded:

```
$(document).ready(
            function () {
                $('#btnReg').click(function () {
                    $.get('@Url.Action("partialRegAdmin", "SuperUser")', function (data) {
                        $('#partials').replaceWith(data);
                    });
                });
                $('#btnList').click(function () {
                    $.get('@Url.Action("partialListAdmin", "SuperUser")', function (data) {
                        $('#partials').replaceWith(data);
                    });
                });
                $('#btnSeek').click(function () {
                    $.get('@Url.Action("partialSeekAdmin", "SuperUser")', function (data) {
                        $('#partials').replaceWith(data);
                    });
                });
            });
```

And it works fine on the first click of ANY of the three buttons, but, after the clicking one, the other two won't work anymore.
I've read some posts here sying that it could be a caching problem, so I tried using `$.ajax({cache: false})`, tried using the `[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]`, tried creating the following attribute:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    }
}
```

All to no use... Anyone has any idea of what could be wrong?

---

Edit:
Requested code for the partial partialRegAdmin view:

```
@model pedidosOnlineMVC.Models.Administrador
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form()))
{
    @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(Html.AntiForgeryToken())
    @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model=>model.nome)
    @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model=>model.cpf).Data(new {mask="999.999.999-99"})
    @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model=>model.telefone)
    @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model=>model.login)
    @f.FormGroup().PasswordFor(model=>model.senha)
    @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(@Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Text("Cadastrar"))
}
```

Comment: I assume `partialRegAdmin` and others return some kind of html built onsome view, right? Can you post this view code?

Comment: You mean the controller code or the actual `PartialView` cshtml code?

Comment: Edited. All partial follow a similar structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
$('#partials').html(data);
```

instead of

```
$('#partials').replaceWith(data);
```

Basically when you click for the first time, `#partials` on the page is replaced completely with whatever html is returned from the server. As you PartialView contains no element with id `partials`, consequent calls to `$('#partials')` find nothing, thus nothing is replaced.

`html` on the other hand will replace *content*, leaving `partials` on the page for further usage.